# Running job on local jenkins with local repository

Tags: jenkins

I have Selenium project and i want to run my job on local Jenkins 2.176.1 from local repository (using path to my project folder on disc).

Do You know where's that option? I remember that I use this option few months ago, but now I can't find box for path to files on disc.

Now I only see git/subversion option.

[[image]]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Linking-**jenkins**-local-git-repository.

**Go to Source Code Management tab and select Git**

[image]

The critical part is what you enter here as the “Repository URL”. The correct value should start with **file:////** for a local repository which is created on your PCs local file system.

For a test project which was created under **“/usr/local/projects/reporting-servicet”** the Repository URL should be entered as **“file:////usr/local/projects/reporting-service”**.

Now save this configuration, go to “Jenkins” dashboard **(http://localhost:8080/)** and click your projects name on the right

Comment: How is this different than what the original question had tried?

Answer (score 1):

@Sunny Sharma's answer works well for a local git repository. I setup a Multibranch Pipeline Project, added the following into Branch Sources > Git > Project Repository

```
file:///<path-to-local-git-repository>
or simply w/o file:///
<path-to-local-git-repository>
```

Where file:/// or file://// both are working for *nix style forward slash path. Even though you're using a local git repository, any changes you made needed to be committed locally first in order to let Jenkins check out and pick them up. Validated on Jenkins 2.263.4.